# Dereferencing an in-memory file held in a Moose attribute

Tags: perl, moose

The following is an excerpt from some code that I'm experimenting with:

```
has buffer     => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'ScalarRef' );
has old_stdout => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'FileHandle' );

sub capture {
    my $self = shift;
    my $old_stdout;
    my $buffer;

    open $old_stdout, '>&', STDOUT
        or croak 'Cannot duplicate filehandle';

    close STDOUT;

    open STDOUT, '>', \$buffer
        or croak 'Cannot open filehandle';

    $self->old_stdout( $old_stdout );
    $self->buffer( \$buffer );
}

sub reset {
    my $self = shift;

    open STDOUT, '>&', $self->old_stdout
        or croak 'Cannot reset STDOUT';
}
```

Elsewhere:

```
my $stdout = Capture->new();
print "Some output\n";
$stdout->reset();

print $stdout->buffer();
# SCALAR(0x#######)

print ${$stdout->buffer()};
# Some output
```

I have tried cheating by setting the attribute hashref directly -- it works, but I don't like doing it:

```
    open STDOUT, '>', \$self->{buffer}
        or croak 'Cannot open filehandle';
```

I think I am missing something fundamental here.  How should I go about storing `$buffer` (an in-memory file) as a Moose attribute, so that I can retrieve it later without the caller having to dereference it?

**Update**

I've added an `around` method modifier, which does the trick:

```
around 'buffer' => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;
    return ${$self->$orig} unless @_;
    $self->$orig( @_ );
};
```

...but it still feels messy.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to make both attributes (`buffer` and `old_stdout`) private by prepending underscore and then add simple method to access buffer from the outside:

```
sub buffer {
    my $self = shift;
    return ${$self->_buffer}
}
```

It also look that you are trying to implement duplicate for [Capture::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Capture%3a%3aTiny) or similar module.

Comment: Thanks.  Without wishing to take away anything from your answer, it was obvious once I saw it.  It's clear, simple and effective.  As for capture::Tiny - yes, it's very similar.  It's part of something bigger, and I did look at Capture::Tiny, amongst others.  I may well end up using a CPAN module, but either way, it's been a worthwhile task, as I've learned a few new things along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the meaning of `buffer` (as you did with `around`), create a new accessor.

```
has buffer_ref => (
   ...
   handles => {
      buffer => sub {
         my $self = shift;
         if (@_) {
            ${ $self->buffer_ref }  = $_[0];
         } else {
            return ${ $self->buffer_ref };
         }
      },
   },
);
```

Comment: +1 That's a very Moosey way of doing it.  I like it, and it was a close tie between this and bvr's answer, which essentially does the same thing.  I was looking into ways of using delegation, and your example helped clarify the use of code refs with `handles`.  However, I think bvr's solution is simpler and clearer, and it doesn't require "metaclass twiddling" (quote from Moose docs).

Comment: @Martin, I always put accessors in `handles`. Better there with the rest of the attribute's definition than halfway around the planet with other arbitrary subs. There's no "twiddling"; the sub is identical to what it would be elsewhere in the file.

Comment: That's a good point about keeping the accessor with the attribute definition - I did consider that as a factor.  What swayed me to the alternative answer was that I tried it with Mouse, and it failed.  I know that Mouse wasn't part of my question, so apologies for that, but it turns out that Mouse might be helpful here, due to its lower startup overhead.